# Identities for operators in group algebras

Tags: operator-theory, group-algebras

Let C[G] be a group algebra for (typically) infinite noncommutative group G.

fix f,g -- functions $f,g : C[G]\times C[G] \to C[G]$. Let us consider the family of operators on $C[G]$ such that for the member $\alpha$ for each $u,v\in C[G]$ holds an identity
$$
 \alpha(uv) = f(\alpha(u),v) + g (u, \alpha(v)).
$$

For example the Leibniz rule is corresponding:
$$
 d(uv) = d(u)v + u d(v).
$$

Here f(x,y)=g(x,y)= xy.

So, my question for the collective mind is following. Who studied such operator families?

UPD: sure the family of operators for which the identity holds don't have to form an algebra, but (for linear functions f,g) the form the vector space.

Comment: As written, this makes no sense (at least to me), because in the identity left side looks at $\alpha$ as a binary operation, and on the right side it's unary. In any case, as inverses and coproduct do not appear in definitions, you can look at that as a particular case of an operad (generated by $f, g$, which generate free suboperad; multiplication, and your $\alpha$). I doubt there's much you can say about general algebras over it, because it's 4 operations with only two relations (associativity + your identity); this is even less restrictive than random non-associative ring.

Comment: Sorry, sure there is $\alpha (uv) $ on the left side.

And I'm intrested in the families of operators, such that the identity for all of them holds. They don't have to form an algebra in generaly. But sure if they are derivations then the form a Lie algebra (not assiciated surely).